LOOCV test error is different by mannually "for() loop" or cv.glm()
It's about Question 7 in Chapter 5 of book "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R". Below is part of the question's text:


In Sections 5.3.2 and 5.3.3, we saw that the cv.glm() function can be used in order to compute the LOOCV test error estimate.
Alternatively, one could compute those quantities using just the glm()
and predict.glm() functions, and a for loop. You will now take this approach in order to
compute the LOOCV error for a simple logistic regression model on the
Weekly data set.


Solution 1: use glm(), predict.glm(), and for loop
library(ISLR2)
error <- numeric(nrow(Weekly))

for (i in 1:nrow(Weekly)) {
  
  fit <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2,
             data = Weekly[-i, ],
             family = "binomial")
  
  # "Up" is TRUE
  p <- predict(fit, 
               newdata = Weekly[i,,drop = FALSE],
               type = "response") > 0.5
  
  # Error: misclassified items
  error[i] <- ifelse(p, "Down", "Up") == Weekly$Direction[i]

}

# LOOCV test error estimate
mean(error)
# [1] 0.4499541

Solution 2: use cv.glm() directly
library(boot)
fit2 <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2,
            data = Weekly,
            family = "binomial")

cv.err.fit2 <- cv.glm(Weekly, fit2)

# LOOCV test error estimate
cv.err.fit2$delta[1]
# [1] 0.2464536

Here is my question:
Why the results of LOOCV test error estimates from Solution 1 and Solution 2 are very different (0.4499541 V.S. 0.2464536)? They should be the same.

Misclassification is a poor way to assess model performance.

cv.glm by default doesn't calculate what you believe it calculates. Its default cost function is "the average squared error function".
library(ISLR)
data("Weekly")

yhat <- numeric(nrow(Weekly))

for (i in 1:nrow(Weekly)) {
  
  fit <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2,
             data = Weekly[-i, ],
             family = "binomial")
  
  yhat[[i]] <- predict(fit, 
               newdata = Weekly[i,,drop = FALSE],
               type = "response") 
  
}

mean((yhat - (as.numeric(Weekly$Direction) - 1L))^2)
#[1] 0.2464536

You can reproduce your result by defining a different cost function:
library(boot)
fit2 <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2,
            data = Weekly,
            family = "binomial")

cv.err.fit2 <- cv.glm(Weekly, fit2, 
  cost = \(y, yhat) mean(yhat > 0.5 & y == 0L | yhat <= 0.5 & y == 1L))
cv.err.fit2$delta[1]
#[1] 0.4499541

See also the last example in help("cv.glm").
You should probably study what cost functions are typically used for logistic regression. In real-world applications, an asymmetric cost function is often appropriate.
